# Position of text in responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position

I have a responsive layout with a background centered in the middle without width attribute specified.
Now I would like to have a div which is aligned right inside of the background image.

like this:

[image]

respond to #Jasper Seinhorst..

This is the problem.. it's floating outside the div

[image]

HTML =>

```
<div class="view_banner" style="background: url({$header.headerimg}) center 0 no-repeat;">
{if $header.copyright}
<div class="copyright">Courtesy Cree Europe</div>
{/if}
</div>
```

CSS =>

```
.view_banner {position: relative; width: 100%; height:476px;}
 .copyright{position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; font-size: 16px; color: black;}
```

Comment: Provide relevant html and css not just an image!

Comment: Should we imagine that this is a CSS `background-image`, or should we imagine that it's an `img` with `display: block`? Or should we imagine something else entirely? Please, please, please include the relevant HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Add position relative to the div with the background image.
Add position absolute to the div with the text.

```css
#image_with_bg {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px; /* remove this */
  height: 50px; /* remove this */
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

#overlay_text {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="image_with_bg">
  <div id="overlay_text">Text goes here</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it diddn't fix my problem.. check my updated question..

Comment: Can you paste your code in your question.

Comment: I guess your image is too small and doesn't fill your div from edge to edge. Can you make your background image 100%?

Comment: it's 1100px width and responsive and has: margin:0 auto inside the wrapper. My image doesn't have any width specified, otherwise it would be responsive anymore.

Comment: It's unrelated but with "background-size: cover" you can zoom to fit any background image to its container. Can you try that?